# Fragments - Phone vs Tablet Correct Programming Habits

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two ways of navigating between UI screens using Fragments and am curious if one is more "correct" than the other or if it simply depends on the Device?

Example: A listView exists within a Fragment, which occupies a Frame Layout container in my Main Activity. The listView is populated with 7 weather forecasts, one for each day. I click Monday and am taken to a detailed breakdown of the weather for that day. Which one of these methods should I use in general, or again, does it depend on the device...

A) Notify the Main Activity through an interface that an item has been clicked and replace the container with a detailForecast Fragment. Basically manage all of the Fragments through one Activity.

OR

B) Create a new Activity containing a detailForecast Fragment, which will launch when the day is selected from my listView in my original Fragment through a new Intent. Basically display the detailed weather forecast in a separate Activity..

I've noticed that A is more used when it comes to Tablets and B with phones. Wondering if there's any truth to that? Thanks!

Comment: I think you got it right!, that's pretty much what you get when you generate a master detail flow using Android Studio. On phones, I usually launch an empty activity reusing the fragment used on the tablet layout